# How i insert N/A Custom Values to the SQL Table Column?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I want to insert the N/A to the `Status` column in my `Product_Version_Mapping` table.

```
INSERT INTO Product_Version_Mapping (Product, Version, Status)
    (SELECT Product, Version FROM FilterCombination 
     EXCEPT SELECT Product, Version FROM Product_Version_Mapping), 'N/A');
```

Comment: First of all, you may optimize your query and try to "screen" your slash: Insert into Product_Version_Mapping(Product,Version,Status)  select Product,Version, 'N\/A' from FilterCombination except select Product , Version from Product_Version_Mapping;

Comment: Also you have one one opening (, but two closing ). I fixed that also

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you

```
INSERT INTO Product_Version_Mapping (Product, Version, Status)
           SELECT Product, Version,  'N/A' From 
        (SELECT Product, Version, FROM FilterCombination 
         EXCEPT SELECT Product, Version FROM Product_Version_Mapping);
```